# Travis CI: What is the directory to cache dependencies in case of pip3 --user?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, caching, travis-ci

I use their `node_js` builds in `trusty` containers with Python 3 addons:

```
sudo: false
dist: "trusty"
language: "node_js"
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - "python3"
      - "python3-pip"
```

To install dependencies of my Sphinx docs, which live alongside my Node.js project,
I do following:

```
pip3 install --user -r docs/requirements.txt
```

These dependencies change quite rarely in case of my project. If I wanted
to cache these dependencies between builds to save some seconds, what would
be the directory to cache?

The [docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/) suggest [something for pip](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#pip-cache),
but my hunch is this only works for `python` builds and only for `pip`. It is possible
to [cache arbitrary directories](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#Arbitrary-directories) though,
so I only need to figure out the right directory.

I inspected the build output, but could not figure out the correct directory just from what `pip3` printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a `before_install` line and search for the dependecy? e.g

```
before_install:
 - pip3 show <your_dependency> | grep -i location
```